# React/Firebase. What to do if copies of an array are constantly creating?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, firebase

I created a function that makes the block disabled when I click on it. When I click on the button - constantly creating copy of an array consisting of other arrays and after the timer expires I get a bug. What am I doing wrong?

I put the debugger in a function and saw this. How to fix it?

[image]

This is my code if needed

```
const CurrentEventsItem = () => {
    const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState( 15);
  
    const getPadTime = (time) => time.toString().padStart(2, "0");
  
    const minutes = getPadTime(Math.floor(timeLeft / 60));
    const seconds = getPadTime(timeLeft - minutes * 60);

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
          setTimeLeft((timeLeft) =>
            timeLeft >= 1 ? timeLeft - 1 : setDisabled() || 15
          );
        }, 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
      }, []);
    
      const getRandomElements = (array, count) => {
        const shuffled = array.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
        return shuffled.slice(0, count);
      };

    const [appState, changeState] = useState( [])

    useEffect(() => {
        getCurrentEvents()
      }, [])
    
      const getCurrentEvents = async() => {
        const data = await ProductDataService.getAllCurrentEvents()
        changeState(data.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})))
      }

    const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState(() =>
        getRandomElements(appState, 3)
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        if (timeLeft === 0) {
          const elements = getRandomElements(appState, 3);
          setSelectedItems(elements);
        }
      }, [timeLeft, appState]);

    const toggleActiveStyles = (index) => {
        if (appState[index].statusItem) {
          return "current__events__hot-price disabled";
        } else {
          return "current__events__hot-price";
        }
      };
    
      const toggleActiveStylesBtns = (index) => {
        if (appState[index].statusItem) {
          return "current__events__btn-green disabled";
        } else {
          return "current__events__btn-green";
        }
      };
    
    const toggleActive = (item) => {
        let arrayCopy = [...appState];
        debugger
        const toggledElement = arrayCopy.find((o) => o.id === item.id);
        if (toggledElement) {
          toggledElement.statusItem = !toggledElement.statusItem;
          changeState( [...appState, arrayCopy] );
        }
    };

    const setDisabled = () => {
        appState.forEach((item) => {
          if (item.statusItem) {
            toggleActive(item);
          }
        });
    };

    return (
        <>
        <div className='current__events__wrapper'>
            {selectedItems.map((item, index) => 
                <div className="current__events__hot-price__item" key={index}>
                    <div className={toggleActiveStyles(index)}>
                        <h5 className="current__events__card-title__large">Hot Price</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div className="current__events__image">
                        <img src={item.avatar} alt='user' className="rounded-circle" width='75' height='75'/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="current__events__info">
                        <h4 className="current__events__title__middle">{item.title}</h4>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div className="current__events__timer">
                        <span>{minutes}</span>
                        <span>:</span>
                        <span>{seconds}</span>
                    </div>

                    <button className={toggleActiveStylesBtns(index)} onClick={() => toggleActive(item)} disabled={item.statusItem}>MAKE TURN</button> 
                </div> 
            )}

            
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with your `toggleActive` function. Lets see what it does step by step.

```
const toggleActive = (item) => {
  let arrayCopy = [...appState]; 
  const toggledElement = arrayCopy.find((o) => o.id === item.id);
  if (toggledElement) {
    toggledElement.statusItem = !toggledElement.statusItem;
    changeState([...appState, arrayCopy]);
  }
};
```

Steps:

1. `let arrayCopy = [...appState];` - You create arrayCopy which is an array that has all the elements from appState, just a copy of an array, shallow copy, array is different, elements inside - are the same, same references to an objects, arrayCopy[0] will be equal to appState[0], if you modify something inside arrayCopy[0] - same change will happen to the appState[0] due to they are referencing same object.This is not really needed in your case. Read about what is a shallow copy and deep copy.
2. `const toggledElement = arrayCopy.find((o) => o.id === item.id);` - You are seeking the element that was passed as a parameter by this element's id. As per what i described in step 1 - that is not needed, you can directly update the passed `item` object. In your case, i mean, due to your item comes from a `.map` of the `selectedItems` which contains all the items in `appState`, same references, appState is not changing in your case, selectedItems also, so in case element is not found there - something is very wrong with the state consistency.
3. `if (toggledElement)` is covered at the end of (2)
4. `toggledElement.statusItem = !toggledElement.statusItem;` thats ok but as per my text above...
5. `changeState([...appState, arrayCopy]);` and here is an issue itself. You are setting state to [...spread_all_the_items_of_appState, [arrayCopy]]. Which means = [appState[0], appState[1], ... appState[n], [array]] which is exactly what you see in the screenshot. So you put all the elements of appState, which are objects, and pushed a new array at the end.

Now about what it should be:

```
const toggleActive = (item) => {
  item.statusItem = !item.statusItem;
  changeState([...appState]);
  setSelectedItems([...selectedItems]);
};
```

Why update 2 of them? Because modified element exists in both those arrays, so we need to tell React that something is changed in both of them, to force a rerender and to force other hooks that rely on those 2 state objects to reevaluate.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! You help me a lot and I really appreciate that! I realized my mistake. But now, after the timer expires, the buttons are not toggling back. I suspect that the problem is in the `setDisabled` function. I put a `debugger` there and saw that the `item` in the `setDisabled` function is `undefined`. Do you think maybe I need to update the data directly in `firebase`?

Comment: Im not sure about if you need to do in firebase, but as i can see from the code you gave - you have only 1 setInterval which sets button state to disabled, so try to visualize the code flow and logic you have. Your setDisabled fn due to `if` are iteranting only enabled items and disables them. And, if you put a debugger before the 1st line of your code - item will undefined due to item appears only inside forEach function body. A little note - dont use setXXX as a methods name, by convention it is used with [xxx, setXxx] = useState, react coder usually expects it to be a setter for a state.